# reactjs image slider navigation function, cant seem to get it working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, frontend

i have a simple image slider with 3 images contained in an array and i just wish to navigate the slider with just 1 function that can go back and forth between images and if you click next on the last image it brings you to first image and vice versa, this is what i could make but its not working properly, instead it displays nothing if you click back on first image, and display nothing as well when you click next after last image

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      imgArray: [ "/img/work1.jpg", "/img/work2.jpg", "/img/work3.jpg"],
      imgNo: 0,
      imgArrayLength: 2,
      current: "/img/work1.jpg",
      headlines: ["Pink Floyd Office", "Led Zeppelin Mania", "Central Perk Friends"],
      headline : "Pink Floyd Office"
    };
  }

changeImg(n){
    this.setState({
      imgNo: this.state.imgNo += n
    })
    if(this.state.imgNo > this.state.imgArrayLength){
      this.setState({
        imgNo: 0
      })
    }
    else if(this.state.imgNo < 0){
      this.setState({
        imgNo: this.state.imgArrayLength
      })
    }
    this.setState({
      current: this.state.imgArray[this.state.imgNo],
      headline: this.state.headlines[this.state.imgNo]
    })
  }

<img src="/img/slider-left.png" class="slider-arrow" onClick={this.changeImg.bind(this, -1)} />
 <img src="/img/slider-right.png" class="slider-arrow slider-right" onClick={this.changeImg.bind(this,  1)} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `imgNo` using - `(imgArrayLength + imgNo + n) % imgArrayLength`:

```
changeImg(n) {
  const {
    imgArrayLength, imgNo
  } = this.state;

  const current = (imgArrayLength + imgNo + n) % imgArrayLength;

  this.setState({
    imgNo: current,
    current: this.state.imgArray[current],
    headline: this.state.headlines[current]
  })
}
```

I would also remove this props from the state because they are redundant:

```
current: this.state.imgArray[current],
headline: this.state.headlines[current]
```

In the `render` method use this.state.imgArray[this.state.imgNo].

Answer (score 0):

from [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

So the first time you call:

```
this.setState({
  imgNo: this.state.imgNo += n
})
```

`this.state.imgNo` didn't changed.

Changed your code to:

```
    changeImg(n){
        var imgNo; this.state.imgNo += n;

        if(imgNo > this.state.imgArrayLength){
            this.setState({
                imgNo: 0
            })
        }
        else if(imgNo < 0){
            this.setState({
                imgNo: this.state.imgArrayLength
            })
        }
        this.setState({
            current: this.state.imgArray[imgNo],
            headline: this.state.headlines[imgNo]
        })
    }
```